# マクロ実行時に表示されるダイアログで、キャンセルを押さないと処理が進まない

Tags: excel, vba

Excel VBAについての質問になります。
作成したマクロを実行した際に、「ダウンロード中」、「保存中」というダイアログが表示され、キャンセルボタンを押下しないと処理が進みません。（添付画像参照）

以下の二点について、教えていただきたいです。

- 「ダウンロード中」、「保存中」ダイアログが表示される原因（ソースに記載していない）
- キャンセルボタンを押下しないと処理が進まない原因

作成したマクロの処理、実行環境につきまして以下になります。

##### 作成したマクロの処理内容

0. 比較させたいファイルを環境設定シートに記載。
1. 比較元ファイル、比較新規ファイルという2つのファイルを読み込みます。
2. 読み込んだファイルの値を確認し、特定の値をコピー
3. 新しいブックに貼り付け。
4. 新しいブックを保存して終了。
5. 0で設定したファイルをすべて処理するまで1～4を繰り返します。

*比較元、比較新規ファイルはネットワークドライブ上に配置しています。
また、保存先もネットワークドライブに保存するように指定しています。

##### 環境情報

OS:Windows7 32bit
メモリ：4G
ソフト: Excel 2013 32bit

ダイアログ表示の原因につきまして、
比較元ファイル、比較新規ファイルをネットワークドライブ上に配置しているため、
「ダウンロード中」ダイアログが表示されてしまいます。
しかし、何度かマクロを実行したところ「ダウンロード中」ダイアログが表示されないこともあります。
「保存中」ダイアログも同様にネットワークドライブに比較結果ファイルを保存しているため、表示されます。
何度かマクロを実行したところ「保存中」ダイアログが表示されないこともあります。

「ダウンロード中」ダイアログ

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

「保存中」ダイアログ

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

長文となって申し訳ありません。
以上です。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 処理の開始時に`Application.DisplayAlerts`に`False`を設定して、終了時に元の値(普通は`True`)に変更すれば表示されなくなるのでは。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
「Application.DisplayAlerts=False」を記述し、実行しましたが、
「ダウンロード中」というダイアログが表示されました。

Answer (score 0):

保存する際のPath名に問題はありませんか？

・Path名が長すぎる
・禁則文字が使用されている
・サーバーとの接続に問題がある 等

サーバーとの問題やPath名の長さを解消するため、試しに自分のPC内で処理を
完結させてみてはいかがでしょう。